# MySQL UPdate where INNER join

Tags: mysql

I would like to update a table based on reading a value in another table.

```
UPDATE contacts_cstm set ld_dt_crtd_c = '2014-06-11 12:26:17' 
WHERE  **id = 'b0bc2ccf-ddfe-81b1-a278-53ba8bd0a93f'** AND deleted=0
```

However `id` is a column in `contacts` table.

Comment: Post the DDL of both tables.

Comment: You wouldn't need an inner join if your `contacts_cstm` table had a foreign key relationship with your `contacts` table. You might want to look into "normalizing" your database before your SQL queries start getting out of control. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Who says, that he has no foreign key with contacts table? You just assume so based on the name `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE contacts_cstm 
INNER JOIN contacts ON contacts.whatever_column = contacts_cstm.whatever_column
set ld_dt_crtd_c = '2014-06-11 12:26:17' WHERE  id = 'b0bc2ccf-ddfe-81b1-a278-53ba8bd0a93f' AND deleted=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this example

```
UPDATE
   Sales_Import
SET
   Sales_Import.AccountNumber = RAN.AccountNumber
FROM
   Sales_Import SI
INNER JOIN
   RetrieveAccountNumber RAN
ON 
SI.LeadID = RAN.LeadID
```

**UPDATE**

```
UPDATE  contacts_cstm
SET     ld_dt_crtd_c = '2014-06-11 12:26:17'
FROM    contacts_cstm cc
        INNER JOIN contacts c ON cc.id = c.id
WHERE   cc.deleted = 0
```

Comment: your answer should be relevant to the question, avoid posting your own examples.

Comment: You missed out the where clause matching the joined ID field, potentially trashing his whole database.